# Spring boot OAUTH2 cannot refresh_token - UserDetailService is required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm using Spring Boot version 1.4.3.RELEASE and trying to set up my Authorization Server.

I have no problem when creating the token or accessing the resources when the access_token is valid, but when it expires and I try to refresh it, i'm getting an error

```
{
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": "UserDetailsService is required."
}
```

This is the request i make to refresh the access_token

```
http://localhost:11134/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=0d17dfee-1185-480d-af30-ba0f1e47831c&scope=read
```

refresh_token is correct

This is my AuthorizationServer

```
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

            private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "security.oauth2.client.";
            private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "client-id";
            private static final String PROP_SECRET = "client-secret";
            private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "access-token-validity-seconds";
            private static final String PROP_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "refresh-token-validity-seconds";


            private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;



            @Autowired
            private DataSource dataSource;

            @Bean
            public TokenStore tokenStore() {
                return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
            }
            @Autowired
            private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
            private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

            @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                    throws Exception {
                endpoints
                        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients
                        .inMemory()
                        .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                        .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_USER.name())
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class))
                        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class));
            }

            public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
                this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
            }


        }
```

Then this is WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
     @EnableWebSecurity
//   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)

     public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());



        }
 @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }


        }
```

if it's interesting, this is `CustomUserDetailService`

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {

        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase();

        User userFromDatabase;
            userFromDatabase = userRepository.findByUsernameCaseInsensitive(lowercaseLogin);



        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Authority authority : userFromDatabase.getAuthorities()) {
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName());
            grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userFromDatabase.getUsername(), userFromDatabase.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);

    }

}
```

Comment: did you received the refresh token with the access token?

Comment: Sure, and i used it to refresh the access _token

Comment: please added the request (curl for example) did you post to refresh the access token

Comment: added, thanks, i make the request with Postman

Comment: i think, you have to send the authorization to the server. Without any authorization, you can access the authorization server. Try something like: curl -v --data "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN" -H "Authorization: basic "  http://localhost:11134/oauth/token. if you didn't converted you clientId and secret in base64, add try this one: curl -v --data "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=yourclientid&client_secret=youclientsceret&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN" http://localhost:11134/oauth/token